# portmap on debian, can I safely remove it?

Tags: linux, debian, sshfs

I'm running 3 http server with nothing fancy on them. it's just apache with a shared directory via SSHFS, looking at the usage of RAM I can see that portmap is using quite a bit of RAM/CPU and I have no idea what it's doing.

```
init-+-acpid
     |-apache2---431*[apache2---{apache2}]
     |-atd
     |-cron---cron---sh---php---{php}
     |-dbus-daemon
     |-6*[getty]
     |-memcached---5*[{memcached}]
     |-newrelic-daemon---newrelic-daemon---11*[{newrelic-daemo}]
     |-nrsysmond---nrsysmond---{nrsysmond}
     |-portmap
     |-rpc.statd
     |-rsyslogd---3*[{rsyslogd}]
     |-searchd---searchd---2*[{searchd}]
     |-sshd-+-6*[sshd---sshd---sh---sftp-server]
     |      `-sshd---sshd---bash---pstree
     |-udevd---2*[udevd]
     `-zabbix_agentd---2*[zabbix_agentd]
```

Do you think I can safely stop/purge it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use NFS, yes, it's safe to remove it.

Comment: is NFS in any way related to SSHFS? because i really need to use SSHFS. thanks

Comment: I disabled portmap on each server and apparently it's all good. thanks

Comment: There is no relation between sshfs and nfs.

Comment: Having the portmapper running and ignored is also a potential security risk, so I'd disable it unless absolutely required (like any other service).